# re order list like in netflix

Tags: c#

I need an algorithm to reorder a list.

Below are the list and use cases

```
Code:
    class Items
    {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    }


List<Items> temp = new List<Items>();
temp.Add(new Items() { index = 1, Name = "manchester" });
temp.Add(new Items() { index = 2, Name = "Delhi" });
temp.Add(new Items() { index = 3, Name = "madrid" });
temp.Add(new Items() { index = 4, Name = "London" });
temp.Add(new Items() { index = 5, Name = "Ajax" });
```

use case :

user comes and manually reorders(index value) the above list

```
List<Items> newOrder = new List<Items>();
newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 1, Name = "manchester" });
newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 1, Name = "Delhi" });
newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 5, Name = "madrid" });
newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 3, Name = "London" });
newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 2, Name = "Ajax" });
```

**Expected Output** after processing should be

```
   List<Items> newOrder = new List<Items>();
            newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 1, Name = "Delhi" });
            newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 1, Name = "Ajax" });
            newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 5, Name = "London" });
            newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 3, Name = "manchester" });
            newOrder.Add(new Items() { index = 2, Name = "madrid" });
```

Please advice an algorithm that produces output as in "Expected output section"

Comment: Why is in the expected output Delhi before Ajax?

Comment: How did you come to the expected output? I don't see the logic.

Comment: @TJHEUVEL, because Delhi's new index is 1

Comment: @PoweRoy, So the logic is like this, user can manually put any number in the index, Case:1 user puts same number in 2 rows, so the first one gets the preference and the next one takes back its old index value

Comment: can you store both indexes? if you can, you could do orderby x.NewIndex, x.OldIndex

Comment: yeah i can store any number of indexes but its for a simple swap or order by. Its a manual reorder where user has the option to enter any order number

Answer (score 1):

One solution i use for this is by storing both a index value and a datetime of when it was last set.

```
class Priority
{
    private int _index;
    private DateTime _updated;

    public int Index 
    { 
        get { return _index; } 
        set
        {
            _index = value;
            _updated = DateTime.Now;
        }       
    }
    public DateTime  Updated  { get { return _updated; } }
}
```

Which then can be used like:

```
// extension method for supporting sorting
public IEnumerable<Item> SortByPriority(this IEnumerable<Item> source)
{
    return source.OrderBy(x => x.Priority.Value).ThenByDescending(x => x.Priority.Updated);
}
```

And ofcourse updated like

```
// method for updating priority of a item
public void UpdatePriority(List<Item> items, Item target, Item before)
{
    if (before == null)
    {
        // append to the end
        target.Priority.Value = items.Max(x => x.Priority.Value) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        target.Priority.Value = before.Priority.Value;
    }
}
```

This mechanism can easily be integrated in relational databases. Unfortunatly, it's not perfect. When you are setting the priority of multiple items within one method, it's very likely DateTime.Now will return the same value which can mess up your sort order. If this is the case, you can use a auto-inc update sequence number instead of a datetime

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can store both the old index and the new user selected index, multiple 'orderby's should work. That will order first by the new index, but for any instances where the user has given multiple items the same index will resolve the conflicts by ordering by the original order